# How to hide items in the solution explorer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've got an Entity Framework Core 2.1 project in which for some reason VS has decided to spam my solution items with dlls, props and target files as you can see below.

[image]

Is there any way to hide these files? Strangely enough they're not even in that file location.

Comment: I would like to know this as well